# Neutral geometry: Let $r$, $m$ and $n$ be lines. Prove that if $r$ is parallel to $m$ and $m$ is not parallel to $n$, then $r$ is not parallel to $n$.

Tags: geometry

This seems extremely obvious, but I haven't been able to prove it. I thought about doing a proof by contradiction but couldn't manage. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: to clarify, this is neutral (plane) geometry.

Comment: In $R^2$ or $R^3$ or $R^n$?

Comment: How do you define "to be parallel"?

Comment: @AugSB Here I'm using the definition that two lines $m$ and $n$ are parallel if their intersection is empty.

Comment: In hyperbolic geometry it possible for there to be line $r$, and point not $q$ not on the line $r$ and two lines $m$ and $n$  containing $q$ that are both parallel to $r$.  Since $q \in m\cap n$ then $m$ and $n$ are not parallel.  So $r$ is parallel to $m$, $m$ is not parallel to $n$, but $r$ is parallel to $n$.  Hence a counter example.

Comment: @fleablood Indeed, you are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is equivalent to [Playfair's axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playfair's_axiom): given a line $\ell$ and a point $P$ not on $\ell$, there is at most one line through $\ell$ parallel to $P$.

To see this, note that the transitivity you want fails - $r$ is parallel to both $m$ and $n$, but $m$ is not parallel to $n$ - exactly when there are multiple parallel lines to $r$ through the intersection point of $m$ and $n$.

Thus you are out of luck in neutral geometry.

Comment: I see. Could you take a look at my question "prove that a line can't be contained in a triangle in neutral geometry"? The proof seems to rely on exactly this false statement, so I think it might be false.